# Случайный порядок условий в цикле

Tags: javascript, while

Есть цикл `while` в котором n-ое количество условий. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы на каждом шаге, условия располагались в случайном порядке?

Comment: Записать каждое условие в массив и подставлять значение с рандомным ключом?

Comment: Добавьте пример условий. Какие условия могут быть в цикле?

Answer (score 4):

args - это массив аргументов.

Также за место массива можно использовать функцию, которая будет принимать рандомные данные и на основе этих данных будет выполнять определенные действия

Количество условий в одной итерации уже сами выбирайте.

```
var args=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var q=5;
var w=0;
while((w++)<10){
    if(q<args[~~(Math.random()*args.length)]){
        console.log('true');
    }else{
        console.log('false');
    }
}
```

Пример с массивом функций, в которых прописаны условия:

```
var args=[
    function(e){
        if(e<3){
            console.log('a1 true');
        }else{
            console.log('a1 false');
        }
    },
    function(e){
        if(e==3){
            console.log('a2 true');
        }else{
            console.log('a2 false');
        }
    },
    function(e){
        if(e>3){
            console.log('a3 true');
        }else{
            console.log('a3 false');
        }
    }
];

var argsLength=args.length;

var w=0;
while((w++)<10){
    q=[];
    while(q.length<argsLength){
        randomIndex=~~(Math.random()*argsLength);
        if(q.indexOf(randomIndex)<0){
            q.push(randomIndex);
        }
    }
    console.log(q);
    console.log('new random args '+w);
    r=0;
    while(r<argsLength){
        args[q[r]](~~(Math.random()*6));
        r++;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, идея очень помлгла)